# How do I create simple module from already existing PHP script that will display on the main column

Tags: php, prestashop

I have already working guestbook script, which I’d like to add to my prestashop on a separate page. The problem is, that I can’t find where to place it.

I’ve browsed through a lot of modules, but it looks like all of them are registering to either left or right column hook. What I need is to display the script in the middle column, which basically consists of only calling one or two methods that will render out the correct html.

I don’t need to do anything with configuration or accessing the prestashop database, or even create a page in the administration. Basically the same thing I’m trying to achieve could be done using an iframe in a CMS page, where the iframe’s url would link to the guestbook script, but that really doesn’t seem like a clean solution to me.

**Is there any simple way to make a separate php script display on the “main” center column?**

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the include able to help you?

```
<div><?PHP include(something)?></div>
<div><?PHP include(something else)?></div>
```

etc

you can place if conditions if needed.

Comment: The problem is I don't really have any place where to put the include. PrestaShop uses smarty templates and I need to register a hook in a module to display in the correct place in the template.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice.. maybe you have to go deep down and edit the code your self. I have no experience on PrestShop as I use my own code.